# rails3: <object>.save! doesn't associate new children in habtm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save, new-operator, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've got these 2 models which are associated via habtm:

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :reports
end
```

and

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :participants
end
```

In the view to update a single report one can enter emailaddresses of participants to associate this Participant with the current report.
Problem: removing a participant by deleting his email address in the form works fine but associating a new one does not work (no matter if the participant himself already exists or not).
This is the code to update the report:

```
num_of_participants = @report.participants.length
count = 0
num_of_participants.times do
 if @report.participants[count].email.empty?
  @report.participants[count].destroy
 else
  @report.participants[count] = Participant.find_or_create_by_email(@report.participants[count].email)
 end
 count += 1
end


@report.save!
```

Any help appreciated!
...this was my first post here, hope it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused regarding your use of count and num_of_participants. Anyway, this is how I'd do it:

In your update view, you should have a form declared like this, right?

```
# views/reports/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @report, :url => report_path(@report) do |f| -%>
```

If you do, then the text fields you use to enter your emails should look like this:

```
# views/reports/edit.html.erb
<%= f.text_field :emails, :name => "emails[]" %>
```

If you are using a `form_tag` instead of a `form_for` then you should use a `text_field_tag` instead of `f.text_field`.

Why do this, you ask? Well, because this way, all your emails will be wrapped up in `params[:emails]`. They will all be inside an array which makes things much easier.

Now, the first thing we want to do is get the current emails associated with the report and compare them with the emails we got from the form. If one of the emails was deleted from the form, we should delete it from the report.

```
# controllers/reports_controller.rb
@report.participants.each do |participant|
  if !params[:emails].include?(participant.email)
    @report.participants.delete(participant)  #remove the link to the participant from the report
  end
end
```

Now, we need to iterate through our emails array and if the report doesn't have an user with that email, add that participant.

```
# controllers/reports_controller.rb
params[:emails].each do |email|
  participant = @report.participants.find_by_email(email)
  if participant.nil?
    @report.participants << Participant.find_or_create_by_email(email)
  end
end
```

And that's it!

```
@report.save!
```

Comment: Thx mate, that works. I have a nested form so I use one more loop now to put all email addresses into an array, then go on as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign an object to a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, that object is automatically saved

Comment: In my case it doesn't, no idea why.